# Scroll bar does not appear even after putting the suitable code on the page in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

[image: Size of page reduces but no scrollbar appears]I want scroll bar on my page when I decrease the size of the page.

I have tried putting the property  enableScrolling="true" in the Page tag of the xml file.Then I have currently put the new tag ScrollContainer vertical="true" in the recent code, which is still not responding.

```
<mvc:View xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
controllerName="com.controller.newEntry" xmlns:f="sap.f"
xmlns:customData="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form">
<Page showHeader="false" enableScrolling="true">
    <content>
        <ScrollContainer vertical="true">
        <form:SimpleForm id="sForm1" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" singleContainerFullSize="false" title="{i18n>addNewText}">
            <core:Title text="APPZEU05"/>
            <Label text="FBU-ART" required="true"/>
            <Input id="inpLegalEntity" type="Text" showValueHelp="true" valueHelpOnly="false" valueHelpRequest="onLegalEntityF4"></Input>
            <Label text="Beschreibung"/>
            <Input id="inpCust" type="Text"></Input>
        </form:SimpleForm>
        </ScrollContainer>
    </content>
</Page>
```

Comment: `enableScrolling` is `true` by default. `ScrollContainer` should not be necessary. Could you provide a screenshot of the app when you expect a scroll bar?

Comment: I am unable to attach image. Could you please help me to attach the image?

Comment: edit your original question, it is possible there.

Comment: I have added the image

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the scroll container, but if you want to use it I would deactivate the Page scrolling, to avoid double scrollbars

also add to scrollcontainer height="100%" width="100%"

```
<mvc:View xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    controllerName="com.controller.newEntry" xmlns:f="sap.f" xmlns:customData="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
    xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form">
    <Page showHeader="false" enableScrolling="false">
        <content>
            <ScrollContainer vertical="true" height="100%" width="100%"></ScrollContainer>
        </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

regards